# Haskell regular expression syntax

Tags: regex, haskell

EDIT: A working regex (take the second group):

```
(^|[ ,\t\n]+)([0-9\\.]+)($|[ ,\t\n]+)
```

Original post:

I'm new to Haskell, trying to use Text.Regex (from regex-compat) to extract float values from a string. I want my regex to match any series of numbers and periods that is buffered by at least one separator character to the left and the right. This is what I wrote:

```
regex = "[^ \t\n,]+([0-9\\.])+[$ \t\n,]+"
```

EDIT: I originally thought this worked properly in Scala, but I now believe I simply got lucky with my test strings. This does not work in Haskell. An example:

```
matchRegexAll (mkRegex regex) " 12.34 "
```

yields

```
Just (" ","12.34 ","",["4"])
```

when it seems to me it should yield

```
Just (""," 12.34 ","",["12.34"])
```

Another example:

```
matchRegexAll (mkRegex regex) "12.34"
```

yields

```
Nothing
```

when it I think it should yield

```
Just ("","12.34","",["12.34"])
```

I'm guessing the parser treats "^" and "$" differently that does the Scala parser, but that's all I've got.

Comment: If Scala does what you expect with that regex, that regex engine must be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a character class like `[^ \t\n,]`, normal regex metacharacters (such as `^` and `$`) lose their special meaning; they match themselves instead.<sup>1</sup> Something like `(^|[ \t\n,])` should do what you want.

I'm surprised your regex works in Scala; I've never seen a regex implementation that doesn't behave in this manner.

<sup>1</sup> Although as FlopCoder points out, `^` at the start of a character class actually *negates* it.

Comment: I think that `[^ \t\n,]` means everything but not space, tab, new line or comma. That works in Ruby and most known by my Regexp syntaxes.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol `^` inside `[` and `]` means **NOT**. Using this **excludes** other characters between `[` and `]`. If you want the regex to match from the starting, put `^` at the very beginning of the regex.

The same thing goes for `$`, if you want to use it as the ending of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This `"[^ \t\n,]+([0-9\\.])+[$ \t\n,]+"` matches a nonempty sequence of characters which are none of `' ', '\t', '\n', ',']` greedily, a nonempty sequence of digits or dots, and a nonempty sequence of any of `"$ \t\n,"`, capturing the penultimate of the sequences. The first matches `" 12.3"`, the second/penultimate is only left to match `"4"`.